# Python: Holding key down doesn't work on mac

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, tkinter, keypress

So I have a small python game where you have a ball that you move with arrow keys. The code that I have works fine on Windows running Python 3.5.1 but doesn't work on Mac running Python 2.7.10. When you hold in the right arrow it appears to constantly trigger `KeyPress` and `KeyRelease` rather than continuously calling `KeyPress` as it seems to do in Windows. This is a problem because in my `KeyRelease` method it stops what occurs in `KeyPress` causing a start and stop motion.

So how do I get Mac to recognize that the key is being held down so it doesn't keep calling `KeyRelease`?

**Relevant Code**

```
    def add_bindings(self):
        self.canvas.bind("", self.right_press)
        self.canvas.bind("", self.left_press)
        self.canvas.bind("", self.right_release)
        self.canvas.bind("", self.left_release)

    #key presses
    def right_press(self, e):
        self.ball.change_right(True)
    def right_release(self, e):
        self.ball.change_right(False)
    def left_press(self, e):
        self.ball.change_left(True)
    def left_release(self, e):
        self.ball.change_left(False)
```

Comment: what is `self.canvas.bind("", self.right_press)` for? why `""`?

Comment: And are you using the built in python and Tkinter for mac?